# What happens to flatulence gasses when you resist?

Tags: intestine

Flatulence in public can be embarrassing, especially if you are locked in, say, in a concert hall. I don't find it difficult to plug the release for a while. The pressure usually drops after a few minutes. However I wonder what happens to the obnoxious gases. Are they released at a rate below the detection level of most human noses or are they adsorbed in solid waste? I did some internet searches, but the research papers usually deal with methane, which is irrelevant because it has no odor.

Answer (score 3):

They are mainly certain **sulfur** compounds that cause smelly gas [(Gut, BMJ Journals)](https://gut.bmj.com/content/43/1/100):

> ...organic sulphides of bacterial origin, primarily methanethiol,
>   dimethyl disulphide, and dimethyl trisulphide, were the primary
>   malodorous compounds elaborated by faeces.

The cells of the large intestinal lining can break down hydrogen disulfide into dimethyl disulphide ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC408582/)), "which...probably plays little part in flatus malodour" [(Gut, BMJ Journals)](https://gut.bmj.com/content/43/1/100). This means that holding gas would give hydrogen dioxide more time to break down and thus reduce its smell.

Avoiding foods high in sulfur (meat, fish, almonds, dates, broccoli, cauliflower, Brussels sprouts, cabbage) can decrease the smell of the gas  ([Gicare](https://www.gicare.com/gi-health-resources/colon-gas-flatus-prevention/)).

**Ammonia** can also give odor to the gas ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC523176/)). Apparently, a large percent of ammonia can be absorbed in the colon. [(Camridge.org, 1984)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0029665184000148)

So, theoretically, holding back gas could reduce the smell of the flatulence.

Comment: I find the statement "you can't really prevent flatulence by holding gas" not convincing. This is the question!

Comment: As often happens, after phrasing a topic carefully, you start thinking about it more methodically. I believe the key distinction is between permanent gases (at body temperature), like methane, CO2, H2, N2, and vapours, i.e. liquids or solids with a noticeable vapour pressure. Most odors are of the latter kind. Vapours will only exits as long as there are permanent gases. Hence if permanent gases can be removed from the rectum by dissolving in blood and releasing in breathing, the driving force of flatulence is gone..

Comment: It seems *very* likely that the gasses are absorbed into blood stream, just in physical principle, just very unlikely that the *amount* generated is in that much of a relation to what will be just expelled eventually.

Comment: @mathieuvanrijswick The odor is due to hydrogen sulfide -- a gas.

Comment: @CareyGregory In the Flatulence topic on Wikipedia you'll find that there are a lot more smelly substances besides H2S, which often is not even the main compound. I would classify ammonia as a vapour, because it has a high solubility in water.

Comment: @mathieuvanrijswick You seem to have read a different wikipedia article than I did, and a gas doesn't need to be the main component to be the smelly component. Not sure what relevance your classification of ammonia as a vapour has.

Comment: Gas smell comes mainly from sulfur compounds and ammonia. I edited my answer and, apparently, there is some logic by which holding back gas could reduce its smell.

Comment: @CareyGregory I referred to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatulence , especially what is written under Production, Composition and Smell. The distinction between a permanent gas and a vapour is that a vapour is in equlibrium with its solid or liquid phase, hence its pressure is independent of the gas volume. If permanent gas would be removed -e.g. by the blood transfer mechanism, which is still speculative- the excess vapour would be re-absorbed in the condensed phase. This mechanism would apply for NH3, not for H2S.